# How do I make a custom ListView without making a seperate activity?

Tags: android

Alot of the tutorials I've been looking at have been telling me to I need to create a new activity with only the custom list, but I want to add 3 buttons on the top right before the listview

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: If I understand correctly then yes !! It is all in the xml

Answer (score 0):

Well if tutorials tell you that you need to make separete activity for list view (aka ListActivity) then they are wrong :) Just add  in your xml for normal activity.

Answer (score 0):

A content layout file might look like this:

```
<LinearLayout orientation=vertical>
  <LinearLayout orientation=horizontal>
    <your 3 buttons>
  </End of horizontal LinearLayout>
  <ListView/>
<End of vertical LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Thomas R. is right
But if you would like to make the list scrollable together with the buttons then this is the way to do it:

```js
public class ListSomething extends ActionBarActivity {
  @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);
      .......
      ........
        ListView listV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listV.setAdapter(yourListAdapter);
      
      //this is the most relevant part
      //you call it after you set the adapter
        setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listV);
      }
  
  
  public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listV) {
        YourListAdapter yourListAdapter = (YourListAdapter) listV.getAdapter();
        if (yourListAdapter == null)
            return;

        int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listV.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        int totalHeight = 0;
        View view = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < yourListAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            view = yourListAdapter.getView(i, view, listV);
            if (i == 0)
                view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            view.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listV.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (listV.getDividerHeight() * (yourListAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        listV.setLayoutParams(params);
        listV.requestLayout();
    }
```

Then in your xml:

```
<ScrollView>
<LinearLayout orientation=vertical>
  <LinearLayout orientation=horizontal>
    <your 3 buttons>
  </End of horizontal LinearLayout>
  <ListView/>
<End of vertical LinearLayout>
<End of ScrollView>
```